# PhD scholarship applicability for low GPA in Bsc and good grades in Msc

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, engineering

I have done my Bsc.Eng ( civil and environmental engineering). In first 2 semesters i got good GPA 3.64 and ranked 9th from 250 students and selected to civil and environmental engineering program. But after that i lost my track grades went down. ( Because i involved too many society works and political works during study time ). Final result 2.85 ( out of 4). Then i started my Msc Eng program and got good grades 3.42 ( out of 4) in water and environmental engineering and i have one international publication.my work experience 6 years as a civil engineer and planning Engineer. My question is am i eligible to apply
for full scholarship for Phd program in Australia. ?

Comment: @Buzz Are the answers for Australia (which OP asks about) the same as for the US? Anyway, I think this depends too much on individual factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to give an exact answer to your question, because one cannot predict how highly the Admissions at one or another university will rate your MS grades as compared to your BS grades. This may vary from school to school, and may even depend on the opinion of a particular person in the Admissions.

I am afraid, though, that you are approaching the problem from a wrong end.  When applying for a PhD programme, the most reliable way is to contact directly the professors who might be interested in working with you. Don't be shy, because you are not asking for a favour, but have something to offer.  Along with practical experience, you have a published paper -- which will add you points in the eyes of any professor whose research area overlaps with the topic of your publication. (Put yourself in the professor's shoes.)

To conclude: wherever you apply, single out a professor (or professors) from that department, who may be interested in your paper -- and send it to them, along with a short letter adumbrating the overlap of interests and indicating your desire to work under this professor. This strategy will boost your chances.